# Importance of angular momentum in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Why is angular momentum so important in quantum mechanics? In every book there is a chapter or more devoted to this topic and this does not happen in classical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Angular momentum is key to understand the atomic structure. The orbits are classified by their angular momentum, {s, p, d, f, ...}. See e.g. wiki

[image]

The picture shows the probability density function. The columns are ordered by the angular moment, wile the rows are ordered by the quantum number $n$.